# Terminal over Serial (UART)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, serial-port, uart

I Have mangoPi pro that Running ubuntu Server 22.04.
I Want to Connect to it Using Serial Pin Headers That is Avalable on it.
I Have a Machine That is Capable of Reciving and Sending Data Over Serial.

How I Can Setup My mangoPi Machine to Send and Recive Data over Physical Serial Bus?

every article that read about this subject only talk's about how to setup terminal to recive from serial not sending over serial.

Comment: Serial port on Raspberry Pi is full duplex. If you can receive data, you can send as well. What did you try and what exact problem you have?

Comment: if i for example send "ls -l" on Rx pin on raspberry pi, will raspberry pi send back the "0 total" (for example) back to me?

Comment: Have you read [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#enable_uart)?

Comment: "*How I Can Setup ...*" -- That's not a question appropriate for this site. As for an answer, there's two parts. First you need to have the serial port configured at the hardware & kernel levels (e.g. using Device Tree). Then that serial port has to be setup as a login terminal.

Comment: exactly, all i want to know is how to configure kernel for that matter